# NewGlobalRef/DeleteGlobalRef when returning object created in JNI

Tags: java, android-ndk, java-native-interface

When returning reference to object created in JNI method to Java, should we return result of NewGlobalRef call on created object? And, respectively, later, when object no more required in Java, do we need to call JNI method to do DeleteGlobalRef on the reference passed from Java?

Or NewGlobalRef/DeleteGlobalRef required only to hold references to Java object inside JNI, between JNI methods calls, and if we simply return created object to Java we dont need to do NewGlobalRef/DeleteGlobalRef calls?

I've seen such thing in a large open source project:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
Java_foo_bar_Baz_create(JNIEnv* env, jclass, jint size) {
    void* buf = malloc(size);
    jobject obj = env->NewDirectByteBuffer(buf, size);
    return env->NewGlobalRef(obj);
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_foo_bar_Baz_free(JNIEnv* env, jclass, jobject jbuffer) {
    void* buf = env->GetDirectBufferAddress(jbuffer);        
    free(buf);
}
```

It return result of NewGlobalRef call on created NewDirectByteBuffer object, and later, when object no more required in Java, there is a call to JNI method that does not call DeleteGlobalRef, but just call free() on the native buffer address.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> When returning reference to `New[Type]Array,` or other object created in JNI method to Java, should we return result of `NewGlobalRef` call on created object?

Only if you *also* want to retain that reference for use in future JNI calls without receiving it again as a JNI method parameter.

> And respectively, later, when object no more required in Java, do we need to call JNI method to do `DeleteGlobalRef` on the reference passed from Java?

Only if you called `NewGlobalRef()` on it.

> Or `NewGlobalRef/DeleteGlobalRef` required only to hold references to Java object inside JNI, between JNI methods calls

Absolutely correct.

> and if we simply return created object to Java we dont need to do `NewGlobalRef/DeleteGlobalRef` calls?

Correct again.

> I saw returning result of `NewGlobalRef` on created `NewDirectByteBuffer` object (real buffer allocated via `malloc()`), in large open source project. And later, when object no more required in Java, there is a call to JNI method, that don't do `DeleteGlobalRef,` but just call `free()` on the native buffer address obtained from `GetDirectBufferAddress.`

That would constitute a leak of the `DirectByteBuffer` object, but not of its native buffer.

Comment: I've just answered that.

Comment: @Dima Once again I've already answered that. I don't understand why you keep asking me the same thing. I didn't say anything about 'practical decision' either.